ESLint no-unused-vars error on TypeScript generic type
I have this simple object class which is meant to constrain possible values to a certain type:
export class Dictionary<T> {
    [key: string]: T
}

But ESLint is complaining about it with the error 1:25  error  'T' is defined but never used  @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars despite the fact that I'm using it on the very next line. Is this a bug in the linter, or am I doing something wrong?
I know I can just add a comment to ignore that line, but I would prefer to fix it "properly" if it's possible.
The rule is configured this way:
"rules": {
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": [
        "error",
        {
            "ignoreRestSiblings": true
        }
    ],
    "no-unused-vars": "off"
}

Potentially relevant package versions:
"@angular-eslint/builder": "17.3.0",
"@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "17.3.0",
"@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "17.3.0",
"@angular-eslint/schematics": "17.3.0",
"@angular-eslint/template-parser": "17.3.0",
"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "7.2.0",
"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin-tslint": "7.0.2",
"@typescript-eslint/parser": "7.2.0",
"eslint": "8.57.0",
"eslint-plugin-import": "2.29.1",
"eslint-plugin-deprecation": "2.0.0",
"typescript": "5.2.2"


I am confused. you have a class named as a type?  I class cannot be named Dictionary<T>

@ChrisBarr What do you mean? That's not a built-in type to my knowledge.

It was reported as a bug here: https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/9811
The team do not want to support Types, so their recommendation is to ignore the line:
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars */
export class Dictionary<T> {
  [key: string]: T
}


Kinda weird to call this "working as intended" when it clearly isn't, but I guess that's the best answer I'm going to get.

Yeah I don't agree with the decision either as the package is called typescript-eslint it should support TypeScript syntax

It appears that you are right and this IS a bug!  I guess I've never seen a generic type use on a class name like that before. I was able to reproduce it here, and when you do not use the T you get a typescript error.  See it here on the TSESLint playground
export class Foo<T> { //lint error here, no typescript error
  [key: string]: T
}

export class Bar<T> { //typescript error here, but that's expected
  
}

I suggest you report this to the typescript-eslint project

I don't see how that code is meant to be a reproduction of the issue. The only errors reported are on Bar.

Yes exactly.  The original question is about a linting error, not a compile error.  The first example does use the type, but the linter is not catching it, and falsely reports a linting issue with the code
